# How to combine IPs from an array and get ranges back?

Tags: php, arrays, ip, range, subnet

For example I have an array with this ips:

```
$array_ips = array();
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.133"; 
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.247";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.184";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.127";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.134";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.154";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.153";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.150";
sort($array_ips);
```

What I need is the IP-Ranges.
For the example I need to get back an array with:

```
32.16.2.150/29
32.16.4.247/32
32.16.8.127/29
```

But I have at the moment no idea how to do this.

I tried manually something like this:

```
$start = ip2long("32.16.2.150");
$end = ip2long("32.16.2.154");
$range = range($start, $end);
$count_ips = count(array_map('long2ip', $range));
echo $count_ips;
if($count_ips <= 1){
    echo '/32';
} else if($count_ips <= 2){
    echo '/30';
} else if($count_ips <= 6){
    echo '/29';
} else if($count_ips <= 14){
    echo '/28';
} else if($count_ips <= 30){
    echo '/37';
} else if($count_ips <= 62){
    echo '/26';
} else if($count_ips <= 126){
    echo '/25';
} else if($count_ips <= 254){
    echo '/24';
}
```

Comment: well, have you **tried** anything so far? also: you should try to define your question better, because right now, it is impossible to solve your problem in any meaningful matter. for example, all your addresses are in the range `31.16.0.0/16`, or in `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: /29 is the number that have the same range?

Comment: I can't understant what is the purposed of the number after the /?

Comment: @Mann87 please don't add code in comments, append it to the question instead `;)`

Comment: @RafaelShkembi it's the short syntax for the net mask. networking 101.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi It is CIDR notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation

Comment: How would you know that a range owns all the addresses in a block or just some?

Comment: @chris85 . Now i get it. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry... Have insert the code above. I hope it is now right there.

Comment: I know it is owned by the self. The whole range like 31.16.0.0/16. But for a summary / statistic I need to split it in smaler ranges. Because for example the other ips from 31.16.0.0/16 aren't used.

Answer (score 0):

I have found self a solution now:

```
      <?php
        $array_ips = array();
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.8.133"; 
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.4.247";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.8.184";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.8.127";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.8.134";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.2.154";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.2.153";
        $array_ips[] = "32.16.2.150";
        sort($array_ips);

        function search_array($needle, $haystack) {
             if(in_array($needle, $haystack)) {
                  return true;
             }
             foreach($haystack as $element) {
                  if(is_array($element) && search_array($needle, $element))
                       return true;
             }
           return false;
        }

        $ranges = array();
        foreach ($array_ips as $ips) {
            $ipparts = explode('.', $ips);
            $last = array_pop($ipparts);
            $parts = array(implode('.', $ipparts), $last);
            $range = $parts[0];
            if(!search_array($parts[0], $ranges)) {
                $ranges[]['range'] = $parts[0];
            }

        }

        foreach ($ranges as $range) {
    $ips_ranges = preg_grep("/".$range['range']."/", $array_ips);
    sort($ips_ranges);
    $count_ips = count($ips_ranges);
    if($count_ips <= 1){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/32<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 2){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/30<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 6){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/29<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 14){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/28<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 30){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/37<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 62){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/26<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 126){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/25<br>';
    } else if($count_ips <= 254){
        echo $ips_ranges[0].'/24<br>';
    }

}
        ?>
```

Output:

```
32.16.2.150/29
32.16.4.247/32
32.16.8.127/29
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read that natsort is better for IPs.

http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/Sorting_IP_Addresses_(as_A_Human_Would).htm

> Sorting IP addresses with sort() does not really work because if sorting as strings, '100.200.300.400' is less than '50.60.70.80' (and not even a valid IP address, but this is not the point here). In addition, there are more than just digits within the string, so a numerical sorting does not work.

This solution assumes that your ranges have 3 fixed octets. This wouldn't work for 192.168.0.0/16.

```
<?php
$array_ips = array();
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.133";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.4.247";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.184";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.127";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.8.134";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.154";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.153";
$array_ips[] = "32.16.2.150";

natsort($array_ips);

$ranges = array();

foreach($array_ips as $ip)
{
    $pieces = explode('.', $ip);
    $current_range = $pieces[0] . '.' . $pieces[1] . '.' .$pieces[2];
    if(!isset($ranges[$current_range])) {
        $ranges[$current_range] = 1;
    } else {
        $ranges[$current_range] ++;
    }

}

foreach($ranges as $range => $count){
    echo $range .": " . $count . "\n";
}
?>
```

Output

```
32.16.2: 3
32.16.4: 1
32.16.8: 4
```

Comment: Right, but you also can't get CIDR with just an IP as input. This doesn't seem to be strictly network segmentation.

Comment: Thanks for your info, but why should be in the array something like this "192.168.0.0/16." ? I say above (example) there are only single IPs inside. Or have I understand it false?

Comment: Sorry when i posted i hadn't seen your point about the single IPs

Comment: @Arnolia yes your solution also work good. But I found an other problem, that is no solution in your and my answer. If for example the ips are: 32.16.0.226, 32.16.0.222, 32.16.0.159 it is right that this are only 3 IPs, but the range is 32.16.0.159 - 32.16.0.226 = 67 IPs so range would be 32.16.0.159/25.

Comment: So the problem here is that we need at least 2 pieces of information in order to accurately calculate that range. You mentioned that you own the entire range, are the IPs assigned at random? Or are you splitting it up into smaller ranges manually? I'm essentially wondering if you have a master list of all the possible options.

Comment: Yes I have a masterlist of all possible ips in our database. The IPs are assigned at random. That seems to be the problem.

Comment: That's definitely one problem. I think some part of the process of assigning the IPs has to change in order to pull the proper range with just that. An IP can fall into many ranges depending on how you choose to segment.